# Drupal 6: Getting the label value from a select field (CCK's "allowed values")

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

In Drupal 6, I have a content type with a select field. The values for this field are in the "Allowed values" option, like this:

```
key1|label1
key2|label2
```

When I load a node from that content type using `node_load`, I only get the key of the field, and not its label.

Is there an easy way to get the label? I thought `content_load` would do the trick, but it didn't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This function help to you get info from cck field: [Getting the allowed values for a Drupal 6.0 CCK field](http://www.mugginsoft.com/content/getting-allowed-values-cck-field)